# Using a script to automate importing XML into Indesign

Tags: xml, scripting, adobe-indesign

I have been using a script that automated importing a XML file into InDesign and generate a PDF. This is using automation software called Enfocus Switch. This script was working fine:

```js
var NameOfFile = $arg1;
$doc.importXML( File(NameOfFile) );
```

Now Indesign 2020 has a menu pop up keeping the workflow from working. It is asking for import options. Any idea how to add to my script to move forward from the menu?

Comment: InDesign's ExtendScript API provides a `app.scriptPreferences.userInteractionLevel` property that when set to `neverInteract` _does not_ display any alerts or dialogs. You may want to try something like this [example](https://paste.ee/p/EfCYU). However I don't have _Enfocus Switch_ to be able to test this.